# Access to fetch at * from origin * has been blocked by CORS policy, even though CORS policy explicitly allows it

Tags: express, http-status-code-500

I am performing a graphql query from my `client` to my `server` and am getting the following error in the browser:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://my-server.com/graphql' from origin 'https://my-client.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I once got this same error in the past which is why I added the following to the express middleware on the server which solved it:

```js
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://studio.apollographql.com', "https://my-client.com"],
    credentials: true
  }))
```

However without any changes that I can reasonably trace back to this issue the error is occurring again. The strange thing if I run the client and server on my local machine (on localhost:3000 and localhost:4000 respectively) the error does not happen.

---

Edit:

On the client I use a library called [GraphQL Code Generator](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) to generate hooks which execute the relevant queries. One of them is for instance this one:

```js
export function useUsersQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.QueryHookOptions<UsersQuery, UsersQueryVariables>) {
        const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
        return Apollo.useQuery<UsersQuery, UsersQueryVariables>(UsersDocument, options);
      }
```

And to execute the query: `const { data, loading, error } = useUsersQuery()`

I am using the following package versions

```
apollo-server-express@3.11.1
express@4.18.2
cors@2.8.5
```

[image: Screenshot of preflight request]

Comment: Edit your answer and add the client code that sends the request to `https://my-server.com/graphql`.

Comment: @jub0bs I added an example of a query that is failing as you requested.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me much, as I'm not familiar with that client library. Could you add a screenshot of the preflight request in question from your browser's Network tab?

Comment: @jub0bs I added the screenshot - I hope its the one you meant. (Black was my-server, gray was my-client)

Comment: That helps. The first problem you need to solve is to figure out why the server replies with a `500`. A necessary condition for preflight to succeed is that the response status be in the 2xx range.

Comment: @jub0bs does this mean that it's not actually a cors issue and its just a misleading error?

Comment: The CORS error is legitimate: CORS preflight is failing. But now you know (at least) one thing you must fix before preflight succeeds: find out why the server is responding with a 500 status code.

Comment: The problem was that the server didn't actually start up but in such a way that it was not caught by tests - there was no cors issue